# How to to auto bcc outgoing emails in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I wanted to save a copy of outgoing emails to my personal gmail account. how can i auto bcc emails to external account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a rule in Outlook to automatically BCC outgoing emails.

However, there are a couple of easy alternatives listed [here](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=72)